# How to configure Flume conf to parse source using regex_extractor

Tags: regex, hadoop, flume

I am just starting out with Flume.  Trying to figure out how to extract fields from source log files using the interceptor regex_extract. However, between the source and sink the log file does not seem to change regardless of what I set in the conf file. Anyone have any ideas? Just trying to go from 1,a,b,c in the source to 1 in the sink.

Source file is simply in a test structure of 1,a,b,c,d yet always outputs in spooldir2 as 1,a,b,c,d

```
a1.sources = fs1 
a1.sinks = hdfs-sink  
a1.channels = parse  

a1.sources.fs1.type = spooldir  
a1.sources.fs1.spoolDir = /tmp/spooldir  
a1.sources.fs1.fileHeader = true  

a1.sources.fs1.interceptors = i1  
a1.sources.fs1.interceptors.i1.type = regex_extractor  
a1.sources.fs1.interceptors.i1.regex = ^(\\d)  
a1.sources.fs1.interceptors.i1.serializers = s1  
a1.sources.fs1.interceptors.i1.serializers.s1.name = extracted  

a1.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = file_roll  
a1.sinks.hdfs-sink.sink.directory = /tmp/spooldir2  

a1.channels.parse.type = memory  
a1.channels.parse.capacity = 1000  
a1.channels.parse.transactionCapacity = 100  

a1.sources.fs1.channels = parse  
a1.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = parse
```